# Обмен данными с потоком

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, имеется форма и поток.

Как правильно изменять значение переменной(-ных) потока, когда он уже **запущен** и **работает**?

P.S.
Код не нужен, интересует только механизм.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам, по идее, не должно хотеться запустить отдельный поток. Если вы воспользуетесь `Task`'ами и конструкцией async/await, проблемы синхронизации отпадут сами собой.

Расскажите лучше, какую задачу вы на самом деле решаете.

---

P. S. Корректно доставить обновлённые данные в поток без «сотрудничества» со стороны потока невозможно. Если вы всё ещё хотите делать это вручную, вашему потоку придётся в определённых точках опрашивать данные (не забудьте о `lock`'ах!).

**Обновление**

Так, а почему бы тогда не сделать всё же async-версии кода? То есть пусть будет много маленьких async-функций вместо одной, которой нужно обновлять данные в процессе.

Если отдельного потока совсем-совсем не избежать, можно связывать потоки через [producer-consumer pattern](/research/221526/).

Comment: Добрый вечер, Влад!
Хочу сделать программу для управления и взаимодействия с устройством посредством COM порта.
И для того, чтобы интерфейс не подвисал, решил использовать отдельную нить.

Comment: VladD, с async-функциями еще незнаком, потоки как-то ближе для меня были (небольшой, но был опыт работы с ними). Собственно и хотел узнать, как лучше сделать и правильнее в этом случае поступить.